# Yii2 images. Status 200 but not showing in browser. CostaRico/yii2-images

Tags: php, image, yii, routes, yii2

I'm using a module yii2-images by CostaRico for my application and it works fine. This module can rename, crop and store images in a specific folders and it does job well. But when I try to render an image in my view all I can get is a path like this:

```
/yii2images/images/image-by-item-and-alias?item=Product1&dirtyAlias=b6e73413ff-1_50x50.jpg
```

This is the render widget code:

```
<?php $imageOne = $model->getImage(); ?>

<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'title',
        'alias',
        'price',
        [
            'attribute' => 'imageOne',
            'value' => '<img src="' . $imageOne->getUrl('50x50') . '">',
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
        'status',
        'frontpage',
        'primary_category',
        'sku',
        'short_desc:ntext',
        'full_desc:html',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Normally, I would wrap it with `img` tag and the image should be rendered. However, it won't happen. Browser shows Status 200, OK. Image does exists and if I will use a path like below I can see it in my view.

`/upload/cache/Products/Product1/b6e73413ff-1_50x50.jpg`

Also, I've tried to render this image using DetailView widget adding `format` options like `raw` and `html` but no luck.

I've seen some guys on YouTube using this modules and they had the same kind of path with parameters and everything is ok.

What could be the problem? Is it some routing issue? I haven't changed the original module.

Routs

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'category/<alias>/page-<page:\d+>' => 'category/view',
        'category/<alias>' => 'category/view',
        'product/<id:\d+>' => 'product/view',
        'page/<alias>' => 'page/view',
        'search' => 'category/search',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Could you please add the code from `yii2images/images/image-by-item-and-alias` to your question? otherwise it is not likely that we can help you.

Comment: Looks like a routing issue. Could you include your routing rules?

Comment: Sure, I've added routs to the original post.

Comment: You probably need to add header information into you action:
header('Content-type:image/jpg');
You get status 200, but browser doesn't know that this is an image.

Comment: Can you, please, show any example of such code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have RBAC or limited access for guest

```
'as access' => [
...
'yii2images/*',
],
```

and route

```
'image' => 'yii2images/images/image-by-item-and-alias',
```